# Convergence in distribution yields something peculiar.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm solving a question that wants me to prove that for a sample X1, X2,X3, .. from a given distribution with density: 
 f(x) = $\frac{1}{2}(1+x)e^{-x}$, for positive x, and 0 elsewhere, the sequence $n\cdot Y_{n}$, where $Y_{n} = min\{X1,X2,..,Xn\}$  converges in distribution to a certain random variable. I've used independence to show  that $$P(n\cdot Y_{n}\leq z) = (P(X\leq z/n))^{n} =  (1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-z/n}(\frac{z}{n}+2))^{n}$$ but when I take n to infinity this goes to zero. Did I miscalculate something? Does this mean the limit doesn't converge?

Comment: Well, one mistake is that if $Y_n$ is the min then in fact $P(n Y_n \geq z)=P(X \geq z/n)^n$. This makes a big difference because the whole point of that factor of $n$ is to keep $Y_n$ from going to zero.

Comment: It did feel like I've made a naive mistake somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: @drhab but $f_X(u)$ wasn't really equal to what I've put above (there's 2 instead of 1 in the brackets). I'll double check the integral anyway...

Comment: I see now (sorry).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it converges to 0. I am sure that limit converges to $\exp(-\frac{z}{2})$.
To see that take $\ln$ from both side and then find the limit.

Comment: The setup was wrong to begin with so this is kind of a moot point.